# Show that the ode has no solution with $x>x_0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Show that the problem $$ \frac{dy}{dx}=-2\text{sign} y+1, \ y(x_0)=0$$ has no solution with $x>x_0$.We have that $$\text{sign} y=\begin{cases}1 & \text{ for } y>0 \\ 0 & \text{ for } y=0 \\ -1 & \text{ for } y<0\end{cases}$$ Check if the conditions of Peano theorem and Picard theorem are satisfied.

$$$$

I have done the following:

For $y>0$ we have $\frac{dy}{dx}=-2y+1, \ y(x_0)=0$.

So we get $y'(x)+2y(x)=1$ and the general solution is $y(x)=c_1e^{-2x}+\frac{1}{2}$.

For $x=x_0$ we get $0=c_1e^{-2x_0}+\frac{1}{2} \Rightarrow c_1=-\frac{1}{2}e^{2x_0}$.

Therefore the solution is $$y(x)=-\frac{1}{2}e^{2(x_0-x)}+\frac{1}{2}$$

For $y<0$ we have $\frac{dy}{dx}=2y+1, \ y(x_0)=0$.

So we get $y'(x)=2y(x)+1$ and the general solution is $y(x)=c_2e^{2x}-\frac{1}{2}$.

For $x=x_0$ we get $0=c_2e^{2x_0}-\frac{1}{2} \Rightarrow c_1=\frac{1}{2}e^{-2x_0}$.

Therefore the solution is $$y(x)=\frac{1}{2}e^{2(x-x_0)}-\frac{1}{2}$$

The solutions for $y>0$ and $y<0$ coincide if $$-\frac{1}{2}e^{2(x_0-x)}+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}e^{2(x-x_0)}-\frac{1}{2} \Rightarrow e^{4(x-x_0)}-\frac{1}{2}e^{2(x-x_0)}+1=0$$ Setting $\lambda=e^{2(x-x_0)}$ we see that there are no real solutions.

Is my way of thinking correct?

Comment: How did you get $\frac{dy}{dx}=-2y+1$ for $y > 0$? Shouldn't it be $\frac{dy}{dx}=-2 \cdot 1+1 = -1$?

Comment: Ohh yesm you are right! So replacing $y$ by $1$ and the corresponding at the other one, is the way after that correct as I did it above? @MartinR

Comment: That's difficult to tell if you solved the wrong ODEs, isn't it? I can think of a simpler solution, but if you want your approach verified then I suggest that you fix it first.

Comment: How can the Peano and Picard theorems be satisfied if the right side is not even continuous? Or do you mean the restriction of the ODE to where they are?